# React Native after Expo Eject errors with NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber

Tags: react-native, expo

I first had an Expo managed project, but since I needed to add a Subscription service, I had to eject it. Everything was going fine while it was managed by Expo. Now, my app can be opened with "expo start" which opens the App in the iOS Simulator and I do not have any error messages. Everything works as expected. The problem occurs when I build is as a Native App, it errors out with

```
JSON value '3000' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber

+[RCTConvert NSNumber:]
    RCTConvert.m:60
+[RCTConvert double:]
RCTBridgingToDouble(objc_object*)
JS::NativeNetworkingIOS::SpecSendRequestQuery::timeout() const
-[RCTNetworking sendRequest:callback:]
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

I tried to search for the value "3000" in my project but couldn't find anything. I know somehow it provides the number 3000 somewhere as a string which cannot be converted to a number. And again, this problem only occurs as a native build. Expo is working just fine. I also don't know at the moment how I would go about debugging this...

Comment: After hours of debugging, this error is going away when I enable Network inspection with React Native Debugger.  I am getting closes to the cause of this but this is weird af.

Comment: Ok. So everything works fine in production on IOS but on android it gives me `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to java.lang.double. Again this is working when using react native debugger and enabling network inspect but the Android prod .aab and .apk version crashes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the mystery. Posting the answer here for anyone else who is running into this issue.

If you do have an expo managed project and you ejected it and you get an error after with `NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber`  for iOS or `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.double` check your .env file. In my case I set `API_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = '3000'` and used it for axios

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  timeout: API_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
});
```

The 3000 didn't appear in my search because it's in my .env file. And this error message went away because I believe when activated the network inspect in the react native debugger, it will override the request timeout. Just a heads up to double check your .env file if you run into this problem.

## The Fix:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  timeout: 3000,
});
```

Note here that the timeout value does not get passed as a string.

Comment: I'm using axios and indeed, this was the problem. Thanks for pointing it out, I was so blind :D The problem is that I thought that my ENV variables are being parsed to different types (numbers, strings) but as it turns out, env variables are always obtained as strings, so I was passing a string to the timeout property